# PC bluetooth not reading

Tags: wireless-networking

The Bluetooth of my PC is not seeing my other device.  I ran a new 10pro OS and I'm not on a shared personal area network. How do I reset Bluetooth I.ve repaired connection?

Comment: Go to settings\Update & security\troubleshoot and run the build-in troubleshooting tool for bluetooth to check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to answer my own question almost humorous.  I resolved my issue by reading the answer to someone else's similar question. My bluetooth wouldn't read because my PC doesn't have a bluetooth device other than my wireless network adapter having a similar driver, which loaded into my system. I uninstalled bluetooth which therefore helped me resolve connection problems. Now the adapter is picking up all the networks. Then the Bluetooth driver reinstalled as a working version and I was able to pair with my other device  by telling it to allow detection and share contacts in its Bluetooth settings.